# Unable to install Visual Studio Build tools behind Proxy (While creating Offline installer)

Tags: visual-studio, proxy

**Background :** 
I am trying to setup a build machine for dot net project . I need VS Build tools.

I have been trying to install Visual Studio Build tools behind Proxy, but installation gets blocked. Hence I used the offline installer method .

I downloaded vs-buildtools from this location "https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15"

I followed this link to setup offline installer "https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/introducing-the-visual-studio-build-tools/"

My command looks like

```
vs_buildtools__1032894232.1529299355.exe --layout C:\softwares\vsoffline --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --lang en-US
```

I see a download window with message "Download is completed."
[image]

Then I see a error window with message

"Error: An item with the same key has already been added.

Press any key to continue...Error: An item with the same key has already been added."
[image]

Any idea what's going wrong.

I thought it may be due to having an old VS in my laptop, so created a new vm in AWS without any VS installation and tried. Getting same error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know nothing about this installer, but I've noticed that you have two identical records in your command line:

```
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools
```

I'd suggest that you should only include every module once.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was complaining about having set the environment variables  "http_proxy" and "HTTP_PROXY". Just unset the latter. You need to do the same if you have set "https_proxy" and "no_proxy" in uppercase.